# PyCharm: running Django tests with Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, pycharm

I'm trying to run unit tests from PyCharm without success in a Django project.

Here is the architecture of my project:

```
- fugo/  (root repository)
    - .env_test
    - fugoproj/ (django project repository)
        - config/
            - settings.py
```

I installed [EnvFile](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7861-envfile) plugin to load .env_test variable environments that are used by my settings.py.
Then I created a Run/Debug configuration on Pycharm
[image]
[image]

When running tests from this configuration, the Pycharm console displays a "There is no such settings file settings". Tests are found and run, but failed, because settings can obviously not be loaded.

[image]

Unit tests works perfectly when run from Bash shell.
What's wrong with my configuration?
Thanks.

#### EDIT to provide info about `DATABASES` settings variable:

in settings.py, I'm using the `django_heroku` package (provided by Heroku) to auto-configure database:
`django_heroku.settings(locals())`

The `django_heroku.settings` method looks like this:

```
def settings(config, *, db_colors=False, databases=True, test_runner=True, staticfiles=True, allowed_hosts=True, logging=True, secret_key=True):

    # Database configuration.
    # TODO: support other database (e.g. TEAL, AMBER, etc, automatically.)
    if databases:
        # Integrity check.
        if 'DATABASES' not in config:
            config['DATABASES'] = {'default': None}

        if db_colors:
            # Support all Heroku databases.
            # TODO: This appears to break TestRunner.
            for (env, url) in os.environ.items():
                if env.startswith('HEROKU_POSTGRESQL'):
                    db_color = env[len('HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_'):].split('_')[0]

                    logger.info('Adding ${} to DATABASES Django setting ({}).'.format(env, db_color))

                    config['DATABASES'][db_color] = dj_database_url.parse(url, conn_max_age=MAX_CONN_AGE, ssl_require=True)

        if 'DATABASE_URL' in os.environ:
            logger.info('Adding $DATABASE_URL to default DATABASE Django setting.')

            # Configure Django for DATABASE_URL environment variable.
            config['DATABASES']['default'] = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=MAX_CONN_AGE, ssl_require=True)

            logger.info('Adding $DATABASE_URL to TEST default DATABASE Django setting.')

            # Enable test database if found in CI environment.
            if 'CI' in os.environ:
                config['DATABASES']['default']['TEST'] = config['DATABASES']['default']

        else:
            logger.info('$DATABASE_URL not found, falling back to previous settings!')

    if test_runner:
        # Enable test runner if found in CI environment.
        if 'CI' in os.environ:
            config['TEST_RUNNER'] = 'django_heroku.HerokuDiscoverRunner'
```

my `.env_test` file does not contain any `DATABASE_URL` variable

Comment: What's the contents of your `.env_test` file?

Comment: Can you paste hare your `settings.py` (Database section only), and `.env_test` structure? @david-d

Comment: @RachSharp updated :)

Comment: @Majid Rouhi updated :)

Answer (score 0):

It could be good if you publish your `.env_test` structure, anyway. I guess your config must have a key contain database config like this.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

otherwise, a simple solution is creating new `settings.py` and remove Heroku function, and directly put the database config and set its values from `.env_test`:

**settings_test.py:**

```
...

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': os.environ['database_engine'],
        'NAME': os.environ['database_name'],
    }
}
```

**.env_test.py:**

```
...
database_engine=<DATABASE_ENGINE>
database_name=<DATABASE_NAME>
```